# Is complement of open dense set measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory

We are given an open set which is dense in  $\mathbb{R}^n$ is it necessary that its complement has measure zero?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: No. In fact, there is $U \supset \Bbb{Q}$ open with $\mu(U)<\epsilon$.

Comment: @5xum can you please guide me further, I have commented on answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

We know that $\mathbb Q^n$ is countable, so let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q^n$ be a bijection. Given some $\epsilon\in\mathbb R^+$, consider the following set.$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty B\big(f(i),\frac\epsilon{2^{ni}}\big)$$where $B(x,\delta)$ is the ball of radius $\delta$ around $x$. Note that the measure of $B\big(x,\frac\epsilon{2^{ni}}\big)$ is less than $\frac\epsilon{2^i}$, and so, the measure of this set is at most $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\frac\epsilon{2^i}=\epsilon$$

Since $\mathbb R^n$ is a topological space, arbitrary unions of open sets are open, so this set is open. It contains $\mathbb Q^n$, so it is dense. And it has measure less than $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon\in\mathbb R^+$.